Zeros of a Dirichlet sum
Considering integers composed of two prime factors $p_2$ (more generally $p_{~k}) $we can form an Euler-type product
$$\prod_{p_2} \frac{1}{1-1/p_{2}^{~s}}  = \sum_{n_2}\frac{1}{n_2^{~s}}, $$ in which $n_2$ are integers which are products of $p_{~2}$, meaning all integers such that $\Omega(n)= 2k,~ {k= 1,2,3,...}$, together with 1, and ask whether the equality remains true and about the nature of zeros of the r.h.s. if they exist.
This does not seem to be expressible as a Dirichlet L-series. If we put:
$$S(n) =\sum_n \frac{F(n)}{n^{~s}}, $$ then F(n) is a function which is zero at $(Z ~\setminus \{1,n_{~2}\}),$ which does not seem easier than the original expression (first above).
For the equality, I think the usual proof works. I suspect there are zeros for $s=1/2 + i t$, but approximating sums, when plotted, are not as clear graphically as those for original series ($n=1,2,3,...$). My very open-ended question is whether we could find a "Hardy function"--or something--for this series with which to explore zeros?

Explicitly, $p_2= \{4,6,9,10,14,15,21,22,...\}, n_2 =\{1,4,6,9,10,14,15,16,...\}$. $p_2$ is the set of products of two prime factors. $n_2$ is the set consisting of 1, $p_2,$ and all integers whose factors are "primes" $p_2$, in other words, integers with an even number of prime factors: e.g., 4,6,16,24, bot not 8 (three factors, repeated), not 12 (three factors, not 32 (five factors).
Initially I found all $n_2 < 2^{20}$ (about 500K of them), and saw that the product is roughly equal to the sum for $s=2.$ This led to the question above.

Your question is not totally clear to me, but perhaps its related to OEIS Entry A065043 with Dirichlet generating function $\frac{\zeta (s)^2+\zeta (2 s)}{2, \zeta (s)}$ where I believe the Dirichlet series converges for $\Re(s)>1$.

@StevenClark: Yes, thank you for the link, which is exactly the function I had in mind. I added a link to the post.

The analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series $$\underset{N\to \infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n
}{n^s}\right)=\frac{\zeta(s)^2+\zeta(2 s)}{2, \zeta(s)},\quad\Re(s)>1$$ where $$a_n=\left{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2|\Omega (n) \
0 & \text{Otherwise} \
\end{array}\right.$$ has poles at the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ along the line $s=\frac{1}{2}+i t$.
